# Does deleting your Facebook account delete your group posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-account

If I delete my Facebook account, will it delete the posts that I've made in groups that I'm a member of? I am not an administrator, by the way.

The reason why I'm asking this is because I've seen peoples' group posts stick around even after having seemingly been "banned"; the only difference being that there is no hyperlink leading to their profile and no profile picture.

Facebook is rather sketchy when it comes to answering questions like this, and I'm wondering if anyone here has tested whether deleting your account will wipe out your posts - name, content and all. How does it differ from deactivating your account in this aspect?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, once you delete your account, everything associated with your account will be deleted (your name, posts, likes, comments, game scores etc.).

Deactivating account temporarily removed everything associated with your account, but your name will alwasy there in your friends's friend list without hyperlink until they didn't remove it.

See this official link to know [what is the difference between deactivating and deleting Facebook account](https://m.facebook.com/help/125338004213029).